# Error ksoap2 serialization

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap, ksoap2

I try to make a simple application to pick up a string of a webservice, I have downloaded the package ksopa2, amounts well made and the correct data (tested on Internet tutorials) and I get the error below that you can, you know that might be? thank you very much!

Application:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity { 

private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/devuelveString"; //Variables
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "devuelveString";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "http://localhost:52335/Service1.asmx";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button boton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Bboton);

    boton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            InvocarWs(); //call the method

        }
    });
}

public void InvocarWs() {
    System.out.println("llama al metodo");
    try {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        final SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11); // utilizar la version que
                                        // corresponda:11 o 12
        envelope.dotNet = true; // para WS ASMX, sólo si fue construido con
                                // .Net
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        SoapPrimitive resultado = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

        System.out.println("" + resultado.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("catch");
    }
}
```

}

Error logvcat

```
04-26 08:03:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(536): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-26 08:03:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(536): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
04-26 08:03:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at com.example.prueba.Conexion.InvocarWs(Conexion.java:24)
04-26 08:03:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at com.example.prueba.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:25)
04-26 08:03:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
04-26 08:03:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
04-26 08:03:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-26 08:03:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-26 08:03:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-26 08:03:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-26 08:03:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-26 08:03:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-26 08:03:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-26 08:03:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-26 08:03:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(536):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to copy the jar(s) to the `libs` directory in the project. The ADK picks the libraries from that folder and convert them into classes optimized for Dalvik.

```
Creating a folder "libs" in the project
Copying the external jars in to the folder
Refresh the folder
Go to properties -> Build path -> Add Jar (not external JAR)
Clean the project
Restart Eclipse
```

Try this also,

```
Go to the Order and Export tab on the same popup window
Check the box against the newly added jar
```

Comment: did you add the jar file in build path from libs directory

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the **ksoap2** jar to your libs folder. Then from your built path add the jar file to your project.

Refresh your project and run. It will run fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

Steps:

Step-01: Go to Project -> Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External Jars

Step-02: Select your Jar file from its destination

Step-03: In the same window choose the next tab of Libraries which is Order and Export

Step-04: Order and Export -> Mark the checkbox for your library -> OK

Don't create any libs folder, it will automatically do.

I hope this one helps you...:)